# how to fix a weedy lawn

Tags: landscaping

basically, I have had constructions and my lawn is killed. I hired someone around may to fix the problem and put new lawn for me. I am not sure what steps he did or didn't, But not only almost no grass grew there, but now it is filled with weeds, and feels bumpy and I can see small and big rocks. I didn't see that originally, because he covered it with straw and told us not to walk on it, just water it. I do not know what do I need to do now. I used grass and weed killer to kill whatever it is there and start new. but the more I read online the more I get confused. should I use power rake to remove the old grass and weeds, will it remove them all? should I till the yard, or not necessary? do I need to remove all small and big rocks and if yes, how? how do I make it even? I will be in and out of town till mid October, is it okay to plant the grass then? should I have the lawn ready and then plant the grass as soon as I come back on October, so I know I will be there to water it? if anyone can help guide me of what to do, I will really appreciate it.

Comment: Where are you in the world? Any photos of the area that you can add to your question?

Comment: And if you hired someone who botched the job, he might be liable if you have to get the lawn fixed again professionally.

Comment: Bingo, Stephie@user19743 please tell us you have a contract of some sort with this company.  There are many ways to get this dude to come fix what he destroyed but let's start with your contract and his licensing.  This was a major no no for a landscape contractor.  He should have placed big sheets of plywood over your existing soil and lawn to protect it from heavy machinery.  There is always 'Angie's List' and 'Facebook' to threaten him with.  Please send a picture of the damage, absolutely for sure!  When you hire someone to do a job they do NOT leave a mess or damage what was already there

Comment: Sound like you should start again with fresh turf rather than go down the seed route- a lot quicker and less likely to get bare patches, plus its a lot easier and less hassle, can be done over a weekend if planned out properly.

Answer (score 1):

As A Landscaper myself, I dislike seeding before Winter. Preferably Lay down Bermuda sod if your in A sunny semi tropical region. Early spring would be best. Water the sod daily in the morning in the first week, every other day 2nd week, twice  weekly after that depending on the temperature ( any thing over 95 Fahrenheit should be done daily. Fescue grass for milder cooler temperatures and especially for shady conditions. Seed the fescue in the spring fertilize same time be sure to water it in same day. ( fescue does not do well in High temp direct sunlight ) you might try Rye by seed if your trying to get the best of both world. ( Warning Bermuda is an aggressive growing grass that can spill over in other areas if not kept in check .

Comment: In most of the Northeatern USA, and most of UK, and many other places, fall seeding of fescue works very well, if done properly. And where I am, Bermudagrass is a noxious lawn weed which is dry and dormant 6 months of the year, and crowding out nicer turf in the summer. We do need to know where the OP is located

Comment: Bingo J.!!  Cool season grasses are very different than warm season.  VERY different.  If you, Jerry, are dealing with warm season grasses I sorta pity you. Cool season grasses are easier to grow into a monocrop and out compete weeds.  The BEST time to overseed or try to grow a lawn using seed is fall.  Before a REAL winter sets in...we water newly germinating seed at least 3 or 4 times a day while germinating.  Shallow and then after the virgin mow, only water when footprints are left visible on the lawn to train for deep roots and drought tolerance.